# Detecting the power state of a TV and launching apps using Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, networking, android-tv

I am working on a Flutter/Dart application that aims to detect the power state (on/off) of an android TV connected to the same network and potentially launch apps on it.

Most of the packages I've tried using (mdns, network_info_plus..) either don't work or seem to be over complicated.

I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do it, preferably without creating a new TV app.

Any insights, recommendations, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!